# Firebase add data to dabase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to add some data to my cloud firestore database. I have collection called users and want to add some data (username) to document called same as UID of user. 
So, first I get uid (ofc mDatabase is made of FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()):

```
String uid = mDatabase.child("users").push().getKey();
```

Then i wanted to add username:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(uid).child("username").setValue("pere");
```

and it does nothing. Nothing in my databse change. What do I do wrong? What should I change?
I have every requirement in gradle files fullfiled. No erros in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the Realtime Database SDK here.  That's not going to write to Cloud Firestore, which is a completely different database.  Use the Firestore SDK instead.  The Firestore SDK will deal with collections and documents with fields, not children with values.

Comment: For the correct documentation to write to Cloud Firestore, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data